# "Input files updated by another job" but not true

Tags: snakemake

I have an issue with a pipeline and I don't know if it is a bad use on my part or a bug. I am using snakemake 5.26.1. I did not have any problems until a few days ago, with the same version of snakemake. I don't understand what changed.

A pipeline part is just after a checkpoint rule and an aggregating step, this produces an output file e.g. `foo.fasta`.

I have rules following the production of `foo.fasta` using this as input file, and that are run again with the `--reason` `Input files updated by another job` but this is not the case and their output is more recent than `foo.fasta`.

Additionally, using the `--summary` option the file foo.fasta is marked as no update and files have the right timestamp order for rules not having to be executed again.

I cannot find the reason why following rules are run again. Is it possible the checkpoint is causing an issue making snakemake think `foo.fasta` is updated while it is not?

Here is a dry run output:
rule `agouti_scaffolding` produces `tros_v5.pseudohap.fasta.gz` (my `foo.fasta`)

```
Building DAG of jobs...                                                                 
Updating job 7 (aggregate_gff3).                                                        
Replace aggregate_gff3 with dynamic branch aggregate_gff3                               
updating depending job agouti_scaffolding                                               
Updating job 3 (agouti_scaffolding).                                                    
Replace agouti_scaffolding with dynamic branch agouti_scaffolding                       
updating depending job unzip_fasta                                                      
updating depending job btk_prepare_workdir                                              
updating depending job v6_clean_rename                                                  
updating depending job kat_comp                                                         
updating depending job assembly_stats                                                   
Job counts:                                                                             
        count   jobs                                                                    
        1       kat_comp                                                                
        1       kat_plot_spectra                                                        
        2                                                                               
                                                                                        
[Tue Oct 27 12:08:41 2020]                                                              
rule kat_comp:                                                                          
    input: results/preprocessing/tros/tros_dedup_proc_fastp_R1_001.fastq.gz, results/pre
sing/tros/tros_dedup_proc_fastp_R2_001.fastq.gz, results/fasta/tros_v5.pseudohap.fasta.g
    output: results/kat/tros_v5/tros_v5_comp-main.mx                                    
    log: logs/kat_comp.tros_v5.log                                                      
    jobid: 1                                                                            
    reason: Input files updated by another job: results/fasta/tros_v5.pseudohap.fasta.gz
    wildcards: sample=tros, version=v5                                                  
                                                                                        
                                                                                        
[Tue Oct 27 12:08:41 2020]                                                              
rule kat_plot_spectra:                                                                  
    input: results/kat/tros_v5/tros_v5_comp-main.mx                                     
    output: results/kat/tros_v5/tros_v5_spectra.pdf                                     
    log: logs/kat_plot.tros_v5.log                                                      
    jobid: 0                                                                            
    reason: Input files updated by another job: results/kat/tros_v5/tros_v5_comp-main.mx
    wildcards: sample=tros, version=v5                                                  
                                                                                        
Job counts:                                                                             
        count   jobs                                                                    
        1       kat_comp                                                                
        1       kat_plot_spectra                                                        
        2                                                                               
This was a dry-run (flag -n). The order of jobs does not reflect the order of execution.
```

It seems `updating depending job kat_comp` is the issue.
Even the `ancient` flag on kat_comp input does not change anything.

**EDIT**

Here is part of the pipeline.
As @TroyComi was suggesting the last development version (5.26.1+26.gc2e2b501.dirty) solves the issue of the ancient directive. When removing the ancient directive rules are still executed.

```
rule all:
    "results/kat/tros_v5/tros_v5_spectra.pdf"


checkpoint split_fa_augustus:
    input:
        "results/fasta/{sample}_v4.pseudohap.fasta.gz"
    output:
        "results/agouti/{sample}/{sample}_v4.pseudohap.fa",
        directory("results/agouti/{sample}/split")
    params:
        split_size = 50000000
    conda:
        "../envs/augustus.yaml"
    shell:
        """
        zcat {input} > {output[0]}
        mkdir {output[1]}
        splitMfasta.pl {output[0]} \
        --outputpath={output[1]} --minsize={params.split_size}
        """

rule augustus:
    input:
        "results/agouti/{sample}/split/{sample}_v4.pseudohap.split.{i}.fa"
    output:
        "results/agouti/{sample}/split/pred_{i}.gff3"
    conda:
        "../envs/augustus.yaml"
    shell:
        """
        augustus --gff3=on --species=caenorhabditis {input} > {output}
        """

def aggregate_input_gff3(wildcards):
    checkpoint_output = checkpoints.split_fa_augustus.get(**wildcards).output[1]
    return expand("results/agouti/{sample}/split/pred_{i}.gff3",
           sample=wildcards.sample,
           i=glob_wildcards(os.path.join(checkpoint_output, f"{wildcards.sample}_v4.pseudohap.split." + "{i}.fa")).i)

rule aggregate_gff3:
    input:
        aggregate_input_gff3
    output:
        "results/agouti/{sample}/{sample}_v4.pseudohap.gff3"
    conda:
        "../envs/augustus.yaml"
    shell:
        "cat {input} | join_aug_pred.pl > {output}"

#===============================
# Preprocess RNAseq data

# The RNAseq reads need to be in the folder resources/RNAseq_raw/{sample}
# Files must be named {run}_R1.fastq.gz and {run}_R2.fastq.gz for globbing to work
# globbing is done in the rule merge_RNA_bams

rule rna_rcorrector:
    input:
        expand("resources/RNAseq_raw/{{sample}}/{{run}}_{R}.fastq.gz",
            R=['R1', 'R2'])
    output:
        temp(expand("results/agouti/{{sample}}/RNA_preproc/{{run}}_{R}.cor.fq.gz",
            R=['R1', 'R2']))
    params:
        outdir = lambda w, output: os.path.dirname(output[0])
    log:
        "logs/rcorrector_{sample}_{run}.log" 
    threads:
        config['agouti']['threads']
    conda:
        "../envs/rna_seq.yaml"
    shell:
        """
        run_rcorrector.pl -1 {input[0]} -2 {input[1]} \
        -t {threads} \
        -od {params.outdir} \
        > {log} 2>&1
        """

rule rna_trimgalore:
    input:
        expand("results/agouti/{{sample}}/RNA_preproc/{{run}}_{R}.cor.fq.gz",
            R=['R1', 'R2'])
    output:
        temp(expand("results/agouti/{{sample}}/RNA_preproc/{{run}}_trimgal_val_{i}.fq",
            i=['1', '2']))
    params:
        outdir = lambda w, output: os.path.dirname(output[0]),
        basename = lambda w: f'{w.run}_trimgal'
    log:
        "logs/trimgalore_{sample}_{run}.log" 
    threads:
        config['agouti']['threads']
    conda:
        "../envs/rna_seq.yaml"
    shell: 
        """
        trim_galore --cores {threads} \
        --phred33 \
        --quality 20 \
        --stringency 1 \
        -e 0.1 \
        --length 70 \
        --output_dir {params.outdir} \
        --basename {params.basename} \
        --dont_gzip \
        --paired \
        {input} \
        > {log} 2>&1
        """

#===============================
# Map the RNAseq reads
rule index_ref:
    input: 
        "results/agouti/{sample}/{sample}_v4.pseudohap.fa"
    output:
        multiext("results/agouti/{sample}/{sample}_v4.pseudohap.fa",
            ".0123", ".amb", ".ann", ".bwt.2bit.64", ".bwt.8bit.32", ".pac")
    conda:
        "../envs/mapping.yaml"
    shell:
        "bwa-mem2 index {input}"

rule map_RNAseq:
    input: 
        expand("results/agouti/{{sample}}/RNA_preproc/{{run}}_trimgal_val_{i}.fq",
            i=['1', '2']),
        "results/agouti/{sample}/{sample}_v4.pseudohap.fa",
        multiext("results/agouti/{sample}/{sample}_v4.pseudohap.fa",
            ".0123", ".amb", ".ann", ".bwt.2bit.64", ".bwt.8bit.32", ".pac")
    output:
        "results/agouti/{sample}/mapping/{run}.bam"
    log:
        "logs/bwa_rna_{sample}_{run}.log"
    conda:
        "../envs/mapping.yaml"
    threads:
        config['agouti']['threads']
    shell:
        """
        bwa-mem2 mem -t {threads} {input[2]} {input[0]} {input[1]} 2> {log} \
        | samtools view -b -@ {threads} -o {output}
        """

def get_sample_rna_runs(w):
    list_R1_files = glob.glob(f"resources/RNAseq_raw/{w.sample}/*_R1.fastq.gz")
    list_runs = [re.sub('_R1\.fastq\.gz$', '', os.path.basename(f)) for f in list_R1_files]
    return [f'results/agouti/{w.sample}/mapping/{run}.bam' for run in list_runs]

rule merge_RNA_bams:
    input:
        get_sample_rna_runs
    output:
        "results/agouti/{sample}/RNAseq_mapped_merged.bam"
    params:
        tmp_merge = lambda w: f'results/agouti/{w.sample}/tmp_merge.bam'
    conda:
        "../envs/mapping.yaml"
    threads:
        config['agouti']['threads']
    shell:
        """
        samtools merge -@ {threads} {params.tmp_merge} {input}               
        samtools sort -@ {threads} -n -o {output} {params.tmp_merge}
        rm {params.tmp_merge}
        """

#===============================
# Run agouti on all that
rule agouti_scaffolding:
    input: 
        fa = "results/agouti/{sample}/{sample}_v4.pseudohap.fa",
        bam = "results/agouti/{sample}/RNAseq_mapped_merged.bam",
        gff = "results/agouti/{sample}/{sample}_v4.pseudohap.gff3"
    output: 
        protected("results/fasta/{sample}_v5.pseudohap.fasta.gz")
    params:
        outdir = lambda w: f'results/agouti/{w.sample}/agouti_out',
        minMQ = 20,
        maxFracMM = 0.05
    log: 
        "logs/agouti_{sample}.log"
    conda: 
        "../envs/agouti.yaml"
    shell:
        """
        python /opt/agouti/agouti.py scaffold \
        -assembly {input.fa} \
        -bam {input.bam} \
        -gff {input.gff} \
        -outdir {params.outdir} \
        -minMQ {params.minMQ} -maxFracMM {params.maxFracMM} \
        > {log} 2>&1

        gzip -c {params.outdir}/agouti.agouti.fasta > {output}
        """

#===============================================================
# Now do something on output {sample}_{version}.pseudohap.fasta.gz

rule kat_comp:
    input:
        expand("results/preprocessing/{{sample}}/{{sample}}_dedup_proc_fastp_{R}_001.fastq.gz",
            R=["R1", "R2"]),
        ancient("results/fasta/{sample}_{version}.pseudohap.fasta.gz")
    output:
        "results/kat/{sample}_{version}/{sample}_{version}_comp-main.mx"
    params:
        outprefix = lambda w: f'results/kat/{w.sample}_{w.version}/{w.sample}_{w.version}_comp'
    log:
        "logs/kat_comp.{sample}_{version}.log"
    conda:
        "../envs/kat.yaml"
    threads:
        16
    shell:
        """
        kat comp -t {threads} \
        -o {params.outprefix} \
        '{input[0]} {input[1]}' \
        {input[2]} \
        > {log} 2>&1
        """

rule kat_plot_spectra:
    input:
        "results/kat/{sample}_{version}/{sample}_{version}_comp-main.mx"
    output:
        "results/kat/{sample}_{version}/{sample}_{version}_spectra.pdf"
    params:
        title = lambda w: f'{w.sample}_{w.version}'
    log:
        "logs/kat_plot.{sample}_{version}.log"
    conda:
        "../envs/kat.yaml"
    shell:
        """
        kat plot spectra-cn \
        -o {output} \
        -t {params.title} \
        {input} \
        > {log} 2>&1
        """
```

Comment: You are probably correct in thinking it's the checkpoint.  Can you update your question to include relevant parts of your snakefile?  If you want a quick fix, try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64211220/how-to-skip-intermediate-rules-with-ancient/64263336#64263336).  It also seems like ancient was recently [modified](https://github.com/snakemake/snakemake/issues/661).  Check the behavior with the most recent version and if ancient isn't working consider opening an issue.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction, the ancient directive is now working in the latest development version.
Do you know if the checkpoint behaviour is intended or is it a Snakemake bug. I don't recall having had issues with it before.

Comment: Honestly I could see it being either.  You could argue it should update jobs because the DAG has to reevaluate and if you don't want this behavior you can mark the input ancient.  You could also say it's more consistent with the make paradigm to not update.  If you can make a small example of the behavior and what you expect it will be a much more effective issue to address.

Comment: Using the small example in the documentation [here](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html?highlight=checkpoint#data-dependent-conditional-execution) (second one with clustering), the issue does not arise. So I think there is an issue in my pipeline.